# how to where relation 2 conditions in 1 table laravel

Tags: laravel, relationship

this is my query table C where with A.test relation

```
$data = C::with('A.test')->first();
```

it work if i use

```
class A extends Model
    {
        public function test() {
            return $this->hasMany(B::class,'TYPE_ID','TYPE_ID');
        }    
    }
```

but i want to where 2 it not work $this->L_ID is in my A model but it did not works

```
class A extends Model
    {
        public function test() {
            return $this->hasMany(B::class,'TYPE_ID','TYPE_ID')->where('L_ID' , $this->L_ID);
        }    
    }
```

Comment: this would only work if you did `$aInstance->test()->get()` it would not work for eager loading since `$this` attributes are not resolved (or not unique) at the time of eager loading

Comment: Can you guide me please I would like to where 2 conditions in relation
It can work if I specify a clear variable. e.g. change from $this->L_ID to 1 in table A ,But I want to use the variable's data in Table A instead, is there any way to guide me?